# using libxml2 with cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, xcode, xml-parsing, libxml2, cocos2d-x

I am new in C++ and cocos2d-x. I need to know how to parse XML with elements and attributes libxml2 in cocos2d-x . I have tried to google but I can't file any exact code example . how exactly are the usage of the libxml2 in cocos?

I found this code from the official site but I don't have any idea how to convert it into cocos code. http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/reader1.c

I am using XCode for the IDE,.

Comment: You are developing in C++. Why you are using inconvenient C library?
In our company we are using [pugixml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/). It's fast and easy in use. How to start with it is [there](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/quickstart.html).

Comment: I don't understand your question. Cocos2d-x is a *library*; LibXML2 is also a library. You don't parse XML "in cocos-2d-x"; they're two separate things. You parse XML with LibXML2, then feed that data however you want to Cocos2d-x.

Comment: I mean. I am developing a cocos2d-x game, and I need to parse some XML file inside. I don't really know if both relate but cocos2d-x use libxml as the xml parser, that's what I found out from the forum.

Comment: the problem comes with how to access the XML files. I am thinking about getting the XML files through cocos2d-x and then pass it to libxml2 parser. but I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in CCSAXParser.cpp and CCUserDefault.cpp you will see an example of cocos2d-x using libxml to parse data. Or there is also [this](http://www.siddhanttewari.com/site/?p=8) solution (I have never tried it).